# Why is continuity assumed in the formulation of the estimation lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've read about the estimation lemma, also known as the ML-inequality, on Wikipedia and in the complex analysis textbook by Saff and Snider. According to both these references, what the lemma says is the following:

If a function $f$ is continuous on a given contour $\gamma$, and if $|f|$ is bounded above there by a number $M$, then  $|\int_\gamma f(z)dz|\le M×L$, where $L$ is the length of $\gamma$.

Now, as far as I can see,
the continuity assumption is not used anywhere in the provided proof of the statement, which seems odd. Normally you don't assume more than what you need to be able to prove something. Am I right? Would it be possible to replace the assumption of continuity with the weaker assumption that the integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ exists?

Comment: You’re right, you don’t need continuity, all you need is that the integral exists.

Comment: Yea as long as the integral exists (meaning $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved) and $f$ is bounded by $M$ along $\gamma$, you get the bound $ML$.

Comment: @kieransquared Good to hear that I'm right, but then why do both Wikipedia and Saff, Snider assume something that they don't use, namely continuity?

Comment: people don’t often state theorems with the fewest hypotheses. Sometimes, this can be a matter of convenience, i.e they’d rather give a simple sufficient condition to check in practice, and other times it could be a ‘pedagogical choice’ so as to not over-burden the reader. In fact, I personally never ‘learnt’ the ML lemma, because it was always something ‘obvious’ to apply in any given situation that I knew how/when to use it even before I knew it had a name.

Comment: Okay, but isn't it in this case confusing that the authors are assuming something that they don't use? Until you told me that I'm right, I thought that I must have misunderstood something and that a continuity assumption is somehow necessary for the lemma to be true, even if I couldn't see why.

Comment: yup in this case I agree, that’s why I put ‘pedagogical choice’ in quotation marks. Also, it really depends who the intended audience is: in an introductory/engineering book I would expect authors to skim over all regularity-type issues. Other times, maybe they may only talk about Riemann-integrability, when one can discuss Lebesgue-integrability. So, the level of generality really depends on the intended audience. Lastly, Wikipedia should only be used to gain overall ideas, not for nitty-gritty details, because it **does** get things wrong from time to time, and is not general enough.

Comment: but at the same time, it is good that you ask such questions because the way you learn math is by ‘challenging’ the textbook: ask whether the hypotheses are all essential, and if not, how to generalize them, and if they are all essential, figure out counterexamples for when they’re dropped etc.